# How to fix black screen on resume for Radeon

Tags: 20.04, xorg, radeon, resume

Ubuntu works great on my Asus laptop, except Resume (after suspend) gives a black screen. I have seen many solutions but these are always for NVidia, while I have a Radeon chipset.

I also had, since the latest Ubuntu 20.04LTS updates, often a grey screen at boot, but fortunately could fix this by adding the kernel parameter `nomodeset`.

I tried kernel param: `acpi_osi=` but this could not boot at all. with `acpi_osi="linux"`

I did not try `noapic` or `nolapic` as the laptop is not that old (mid 2018).

The resume basically works, as I can log in from another system using ssh. The problem must be in the video. I am using the ubuntu radeon drivers.

I looked at https://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide#Suspend.2FHibernation but I could not run Compiz Fusion, an error occurred and I was forced to log out.

I tried to restart graphics by logging in from another system and issue: `sudo service restart display-manager`  but the screen stayed black.

Any help is greatly appreciated as suspend/resume would be very useful

---

Basically, I fixed this problem by installing the next version of Ubuntu. (The upgrade option would come half a year later...)

Comment: Not a solution, but can you restart the graphic interface after resume by pressing alt-ctrl-f3 and then alt-ctrl-f2

Comment: @CharlesGreen I tried to restart graphics by logging in from another system and issue: `sudo service restart display-manager`  but the screen stayed black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6  (with the basic AMD Radeon integrated graphics card).
The solution was to install the drivers from AMD [website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20) . i just downloaded the archive, run `./amdgpu-install` and i got a bunch of errors but  at the end of it all, it manages to resume successfully.

Comment: sounds great. will try this at home, after work

Comment: Disclaimer: I found this answer useful, but to be honest, I don't exactly know if this solved my problem. Reason is that I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. This was not easy, as the upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS came as late as october 2022, so in april 2022 I had to do a fresh install of 22.04 LTS, with all the troubles of reinstalling all the extra needed packages